# Implementing something like jQuery's animate() function in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, properties

I'm new to C# and using it to write my next game.  Coming from a background in C++, Java and JavaScript, I'm excited to use C#'s anonymous functions to simplify tasks that weren't so simple in C++ and Java.

Particularly, I'd like to implement a system in my code that works similar to jQuery's animate() function: easing a set of variables from their initial values to a new set of values, and then executing a callback upon completion.  I understand how to use anonymous functions and callbacks in C#, so that's no problem, but I'm not sure how I'd go about passing properties and their associated values to a function.

As an example, my goal would be something like this, to ease a player's x coordinate from the initial value to the target value of 500, while easing his scale value to 2.0f, over the course of 10.0 seconds:

```
game.animate( { player.x: 500, player.scale: 2.0f }, 10.0f, delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Callback has been called!"); }
```

(That won't compile, of course, but the point of the example is to describe the syntax I'm hoping to approximate.)

According to other Stack Overflow questions and answers, it's not possible to pass property references to functions in C#, so passing player.x and player.scale to the function would apparently be impossible in this way, which means I have to rethink my strategy for implementing this.

Is there any other way I could go about implementing a system like this, given C#'s constraints about passing property references to functions?  Or do I need to just give up on this idea and use less flexible means of easing property values over time?

Comment: `it's not possible to pass property references to functions in C#`. It is using `out` or `ref` in the method declaration. Otherwise you could just pass a reference type like "Player".

Comment: @Shoe Thanks, I'll give that a shot.  It's possible I misread the other questions on SO, or maybe things have changed since those posts were made.

Comment: @Shoe It didn't work; in the call to the function, I'm getting a compilation error that says I can't pass properties as ref parameters.

My function signature looks like this:

    public void Animate(ref float property, float targetValue, Action callback=null)

And the call looks like this:

    game.Animate (ref this.x, 900.0f, null);

Comment: What I would do is define some reference type to pass in rather than trying to pass the properties.

Comment: @Shoe I'm not sure what you mean (please excuse my ignorance with C#) - I thought my last example was passing a reference type.

As an alternative way of accomplishing the same end goal, though, here's a slightly different and simpler question: assuming my classes ("Player", "Monster", etc.) all have a function called SetX(), which takes a float and returns void, would it be possible to pass that SetX() function as a parameter to another function?  So the other function is using somebody's SetX() function, but it never knows whose until runtime.

Comment: You can pass value types and fields by reference but not auto-properties (excuse me if I made it seem like you could). If you have classes "Player", and "Monster" with function "SetX" and you want a method to call that function, then you could define an interface between them, write a method signature using that interface, and call the method using instances of either of your classes. It depends whether your method needs to reference the instance of "Player" for some work to do, otherwise you could just pass the function.

Comment: @Shoe Thanks for your help, sorry I forgot to mention another constraint in my last comment: the name of the function is unknown.  But with some experimentation, I was able to figure out a working example, and I'll post an answer with an example shortly.  Thanks again for your help though; I wouldn't have been able to figure it out without your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little experimentation and help from Shoe's comments, I came up with a solution.

First, the assumption is made that all properties will be floats.  Secondly, each property (player.x, player.scale, etc.) will need an explicitly-defined setter (player.SetX(), player.SetScale(), etc.) which takes in a single float and returns void.

After that, the main code can be defined like so:

```
public delegate void PropertySetter(float newVal);

public void Animate(PropertySetter setter, float time, float valToSet, Action callback=null)
{
   // the implementation-specific code for interpolating values will go here.  and call "callback" when complete, if it's non-null.
}
```

And to use the Animate() function, all we need to do is call it like so:

```
Animate(player.SetX, 10.0f, 500.0f);
Animate(player.SetScale, 10.0f, 2.0f);
```

I'm going to change it later to allow those calls to happen in a single call, but this serves as a simple example.